# Using mean imputation for different variables

Tags: r

I have a data set where data are missing. Here is a sample of what my data looks like:

```
df<-read.csv(id, test1, test2, test3
1, 9, 1, 3
2, 8, 2, NA
3, NA, 3, NA
4, 1, 3, 4
5, 2, 44, NA
6, 4, 4, 1
7, NA, NA, NA)
```

How would I input the respective mean of each test into the corresponding column for each NA?

Output should look like

```
id  test1   test2  test3
1, 9, 1, 3
2, 8, 2, 2.66
3, 4.8, 3, 2.66
4, 1, 3, 4
5, 2, 44, 2.66
6, 4, 4, 1
7, 4.8, 9.5, 2.66
```

Comment: You should not be doing that. It distorts the statistical properties of your dataset.

Answer (score 2):

An option would be `na.aggregate`

```
library(zoo)
df[-1] <- na.aggregate(df[-1])
```